# json post retrieved data could not fetch

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel-5

I have this json script and I successfully retrieved the data that consist of 3 arrays of json object (console.log)

```
 $.post("/sales", {dataKey: "pullout"}, function(response){
    if(response.success){
        $.each(response.portfolio, function(index, value){
            alert("value.creation_date");
        });
        $.each(response.var, function(index, value){
            alert("value.creation_date");
        });
        $.each(response.par, function(index, value){
            alert("value.creation_date");
        });
    }
 }, 'json');
```

and I got this result from the "console.log(response)"
[image]

either using "console.log(response.portfolio)", "console.log(response.var)", or "console.log(response.par)", I get a result of the data that I wanted to retrieved. But if I want to parse it with this (refer below)

```
$.each(response.portfolio, function(index, value){
    alert("value.creation_date");
});
$.each(response.var, function(index, value){
    alert("value.creation_date");
});
$.each(response.par, function(index, value){
    alert("value.creation_date");
});
```

it returns me this (refer below)
[image]

so obviously, what I want to do (base from the referenced script above) I want to loop through each of the array objects of portfolio array, par array and var array and get each "creation_date" object but unfortunately, its not working. Any ideas, clues, help, suggestion, recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `portfolio`, `par` and `var` are still strings.

Get the object using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Your code becomes:

```
var portfolio = JSON.parse(response.portfolio);
$.each(portfolio, function(index, value){
    alert(value.creation_date);
});
```

Comment: alert("value.creation_date"); shouldnt it be without the double quote?

Comment: @Mox, saw that at first but still forgot. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

As @incognito already said the values of `response.portfolio`, `response.par` and `response.var` are strings. What you have to do is to parse those strings as JSON:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(response.portfolio), function(index, value){
    alert("value.creation_date");
});
```